# My Files are all classified as "Other"

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

In Finder, every single file on my disk is classified under the "Other" section.  However, when I go to "about this Mac", it shows only  a fraction of my disk is actually "Other".

How do I fix this?  And does this have any other harmful consequences?

I have tried clearing the NVRAM and PRAM. I've tried rebooting and deleting the Finder preferences. I've updated Mac OS X.  None of those fixed it.

Edit: this only happens with my account so it probably can't be anything wrong with CoreServices. Maybe a messed up setting?

Here's an example screenshot of how things look:

[image: Example]

Comment: is it same in another view ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, it is

Comment: sounds like first to try to restore the preferences, than double check if it works if you log in as different user, or try starting in safe mode to exclude 3d party apps. in disk utility, than reinstall the os x using the cmd+r

Comment: @Buscar웃  how exactly would I restore the preferences? If I restore, the OS X won't delete my data or anything right? I'd do have a backup.

Comment: Normally installing OS X only installs system files and leaves your files untouched (normally!) To fix the permissions (not preferences), Open Disk utility in the Utility folder and you see it in there. You can also run the verify disk and repair disk from there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Okay, thanks for the help! I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: Is it my imagination, or is that a very strange view? It's set to Icon, but it almost looks like CoverFlow.

Comment: Along with this, my computer seems to be frequently crashing and I am presented with the "Your Computer has been restarted because of a problem" This also happens about 3 times before I can use my computer again

Comment: @Buscar웃 My computer is pretty messed up, permissions / disk checking  didn't do anything. I guess I have to reinstall

Comment: @Buscar웃 in safe mode, All my Files is blank

Comment: @vihan1086, It looks like you've got your view options set to show only `tags` — specifically `other`. In the right hand corner of the `All My Files` window `Control-Click` the text that reads `Show All (1,950)`. You should then see a menu which lets to `Arrange or Sort` by `Name`, `Kind`, etc.

Comment: @l'L'l That did it! Can't believe it was a simple as that, could you write that as a question so I could award you the bounty?

Comment: Just one more thing is that, image files and PDF documents and a few others aren't being sorted. Is there a way to fix these too

Comment: @vihan1086, Sure I'd be happy to write that up as an answer. For your `PDF` documents you would normally find them under `Kind`, but you can also sort by multiple criteria. For example you could specify sort by `Kind`, and `Tag` with `Image` or `PDF` — hope that makes sense.

Comment: @l'L'l okay, I'll check that out, thanks for all the help

Comment: vihan1086:  The default is "Kind".  @l'L'l I've learned something new here.  Please compose that as an answer so that I can upvote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance `All My Files` are being exclusively sorted by `Tags`. The problem here is that this is not exactly obvious or apparent. There are several ways to adjust how files are arranged or sorted in `Finder`. I find one of the easiest and most convenient ways is to:

> <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Click</kbd> within the window or heading.

(In this case control-clicking `Show All` in the right corner).

Control Mouse Clicking the inside the window or heading above the files should reveal a menu that shows the options `View`, `Arrange By`, and `View Options`. From there select whichever criteria you might prefer files `Arrange By` - (`Name`, `Kind`, `Application`, etc).

<sub>One thing to note is that within `View Options` you can choose to `Sort By` instead of `Arrange By`, or even both; this can lead to some confusion in itself (which is briefly touched upon [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/arrange-by-exact-file-type-not-just-by-kind-in-os-x-lion/25182#25182)).</sub>

The <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys while mouse clicking within `Finder` windows can reveal options and menus that directly affect what appears — don't hesitate to discover what's there.

Comment: One more thing you might not be aware of is that after you control-click `Show All` and the menu appears you can press the `Option` key which will allow you to `Sort By` rather than `Arrange By`. Pressing `Option` within `Finder` menus has this behavior in many places (eg. `File` > `Save` would become `Save as...`).

Answer (score 2):

This could be the symptom of a corrupt spotlight database.

You can reset the indexing by opening the `terminal` app and entering the following command:

`sudo mdutil -E /`

Comment: It reset the indexing but that didn't work. On the "About this Mac" it shows files as their correct type. I don't think it's an indexing issue, I'll create another account and see if it's just me

Comment: Weird, this is only happening in my account

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a broken "All My Files" search criteria.

You can check this by clicking on the gear/action icon.  Choosing "show search criteria".  It should say "Any of the following are true: Kinds is Document, or Kind is Other com.microsoft., or Kind is Archive.

The contents of `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch/search.savedSearch` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CompatibleVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>RawQuery</key>
    <string>((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))</string>
    <key>RawQueryDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FinderFilesOnly</key>
        <true/>
        <key>RawQuery</key>
        <string>((kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = "com.microsoft.*"cdw) || (kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.archive))</string>
        <key>SearchScopes</key>
        <array>
        <string>kMDQueryScopeMyFiles</string>
        </array>
        <key>UserFilesOnly</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>SearchCriteria</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AnyAttributeContains</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CurrentFolderPath</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users</string>
        </array>
        <key>FXCriteriaSlices</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>criteria</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com_apple_CompoundSliceAny</string>
                    <integer>20000</integer>
                </array>
                <key>displayValues</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Any</string>
                    <string>of the following are true</string>
                </array>
                <key>rowType</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>subrows</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>criteria</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>kMDItemKind</string>
                            <integer>300</integer>
                            <integer>403</integer>
                        </array>
                        <key>displayValues</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>Kind</string>
                            <string>is</string>
                            <string>documents</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>rowType</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>subrows</key>
                        <array/>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>criteria</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>kMDItemKind</string>
                            <integer>300</integer>
                            <integer>417</integer>
                            <integer>104</integer>
                        </array>
                        <key>displayValues</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>Kind</string>
                            <string>is</string>
                            <string>other</string>
                            <string>com.microsoft.</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>rowType</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>subrows</key>
                        <array/>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>criteria</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>kMDItemKind</string>
                            <integer>300</integer>
                            <integer>419</integer>
                        </array>
                        <key>displayValues</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>Kind</string>
                            <string>is</string>
                            <string>archives</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>rowType</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>subrows</key>
                        <array/>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FXScope</key>
        <integer>1396925814</integer>
        <key>FXScopeArrayOfPaths</key>
        <array>
          <string>kMDQueryScopeMyFiles</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: The "show search criteria" is exactly how you described. I'll check back in a bit

Comment: No, that didn't work. I copied the .plist to match what you had and a the show search criteria matches. I restarted Finder after each change also