# Finder: Group by file extension option

Tags: macos, finder

I've made some search but can not find if there is any way to group files by extensions on **Finder**. But all the titles are from a few versions ago of macOS.

On **Finder** group names are as undetailed as possible and although the grouping is **Kind** the group names and **Kind column** values do not match.

[image: View Options]

[image: Kind Column]

Is there any way to add **Extensions** option to **Group By** dropdown under **Finder**'s **View Options** for recent versions of macOS (eg: Big Sur)?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can search by file extension.

Comment: That is possible too but I need grouping by extension to work on files more efficiently. Searching by file extension is a different thing and unfortunately that won't work for me.

Comment: What about "sort by" instead of "group by"? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/arrange-by-exact-file-type-not-just-by-kind-in-os-x-lion

Comment: I'm also sorting by kind but grouping by kind (file type) is most efficient to work with. Windows has it and it is very useful.